# Issue with ipcMain.handle() not returning any value to ipcRenderer.invoke()

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, ipc, electron-react

So, I struggled with this problem for 2 days, looking in the API documentation of Electron.js and various sites and you guys are my last hope:

Here are the 3 files related to the issue:

main.ts (not the entire file):

```
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  ipcMain.on("set-credentials", (event, args: object) => {
    encryptedCredentials = safeStorage.encryptString(JSON.stringify(args));
  });

  ipcMain.handle("get-credentials", async (event, args: null) => {
    const decryptedCredentials = await JSON.parse(
      safeStorage.decryptString(encryptedCredentials)
    );
    return decryptedCredentials;
  });

  createWindow();
});
```

preload.ts (entire file):

```
import { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } from "electron";

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electronAPI", {
  setStoredCredentials: async (args: object) =>
    await ipcRenderer.send("set-credentials", args),
  getStoredCredentials: () => {
    ipcRenderer.invoke("get-credentials");
  },
});
```

Login.tsx (not the entire file):

```
const setStoredCredentials = async (e: any, service: string) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.electronAPI.setStoredCredentials({
      service,
      username: e.target[0].value,
      password: e.target[1].value,
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.electronAPI.getStoredCredentials().then(
        (data: object) => { console.log(data); } //testing 

      )
    }, 1000)
  };
```

(the electron app features React)

So to solve the issue I tried using `ipcMain.on` and `ipcRenderer.sendSync` with `event.returnValue`, didn't work either.
I get the following error with the current code:

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
```

and the other methods I tried either gave the same error or an `undefined` value.

Answer (score 3):

Two-way IPC needs `async/await` in the renderer process. IPC may spend a bit time. Without `async/await`, the original call just gets a `Promise`.

Try to add `await` to both `setStoredCredentials` and `getStoredCredentials`.

```js
const setStoredCredentials = async (e: any, service: string) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await window.electronAPI.setStoredCredentials({
      service,
      username: e.target[0].value,
      password: e.target[1].value,
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      await window.electronAPI.getStoredCredentials().then(
        (data: object) => { console.log(data); } //testing 

      )
    }, 1000)
  };
```

If the code above works, `setTimeout` can be removed.

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply, unfortunately it didn't work (you forgot to add async in the setTimeout by the way).

Comment: You can remove setTimeout and add "then" to setStoredCredentials for asynchronous. And I wonder why two "setStoredCreadtials" dont' conflict in login.tsx.

Answer (score 0):

just a small clarification:

when I do a `console.log()` of the value to return in `main.ts` before returning it it works just fine.

Also the `cryptedCredentials` var is declared as follows: `let cryptedCredentials: Buffer;`